# Connect Xray 2.6.3 Docker Installation with Artifacotry using Selfsigned certificarte

Tags: installation, artifactory, jfrog-xray

As I am tasked with evaluating JFrog Xray for my organization, I got an evaluation license, chonse the Docker Installation, installed it on a VM I provisioned and am now trying to connect to our Artifactory test instance.

Our Artifactory test instance sits behind an nginx and can be accessed on HTTPS signed by our in-house CA. So now trying to connect Xray to it while doing the basic setup, Xray obviously complains about not knowing the CA. So I checked the documentation how to get around this and I read the following:

> From version 2.0, the sslnsecure parameter was removed from the xray_config.yaml file. This configuration has moved to the General Settings in the Xray UI.

Do I somehow misunderstand this (I mean I must unless this feature has never been tested), because to me this seems to be a chicken and eggs problem right now: I need to set this in General Settings, which I will be able to reach once I'm through with that setup wizard I am stuck in right now, however I need that setting in order to be able to continue in said wizard.

That being said: Is there any supported way to get this working or do I need to disable SSL in Artifactory or set setup a Proxy that terminates SSL in order to continue here?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? We have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

From Xray 2.6.0, you can also set the `SSL Insecure` option in the on-boarding wizard:

[image]

Comment: This disable the ssl check on xray itself,and not on the target artifactory instance, right? If so it does not solve the problem asked in the original post